# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 - How to Implement IIdentityMessageService to do Async SMTP using SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, smtpclient

I've implemented a simple EmailService for Asp.Net Identity 2.0 (via the `IIdentityMessageService` interface.

```
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // convert IdentityMessage to a MailMessage
        var email = 
           new MailMessage(new MailAddress("noreply@mydomain.com", "(do not reply)"), 
           new MailAddress(message.Destination))
        {
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Body = message.Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient()) // SmtpClient configuration comes from config file
        {
            return client.SendMailAsync(email);
        }
    }
}
```

To send an email, I go through UserManager:

`await _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account","Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");`

The problem is that I get a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` when I call `SendEmailAsync()` and it's not clear why.

If I send email synchronously (`client.Send(email)`), everything works fine.

So my questions are:

- How do I prevent the TaskCanceledException from getting thrown?
  and (assuming I can overcome this error),
- How should I go about communicating errors during email sending back to the client (i.e., "no such user here" type responses from the SmtpClient?

Comment: Here is your details answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45789677/3835843

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your problem is that `SmtpClient` is disposed before the email is sent.

Two ways:

- Await the `SendMailAsync` result

  ```
  using (var client = new SmtpClient())
  {
      await client.SendMailAsync(email);
  }
  ```
- Register the `SendCompleted` event and dispose the `SmtpClient` only after the message is sent

  ```
  var client = new SmtpClient();
  client.SendCompleted += (s, e) => {
      client.Dispose();
  };
  return client.SendMailAsync(message);
  ```

Comment: I can't await the SendMailAsync() (at least not with out some more gymnastics) because the IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync() method has a return type of Task. But the second suggestion looks like it's going to work. Thanks.

Comment: You can await the `SendMailAsync` method. Add `async`/`await` and do not return anything. The compiler will do his job.

Comment: I faced this same issue and wrote up a complete description here: http://blog.falafel.com/avoid-taskcanceledexception-sending-email-async/

Comment: what if I make `client` static?

Comment: In this case, you need to make sure all `SendMailAsync` has completed before disposing the client. You can ask a new question with your code, so we can help you.

Comment: My realization is very simple. It works without any errors (noticeable, at least):
    `public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        static SmtpClient Sender =new SmtpClient();
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage m)
        {
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ 
                Sender.Send(new MailMessage("robot@service.com", m.Destination,m.Subject,"<html><body>"+m.Body+"</body></html>"){IsBodyHtml=true});
            });
        }
    }`
But I now I'm in doubt if it is really correct. Especially with that approach to `async` method.

Answer (score 9):

You must put async on method.

```
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
                using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage("your@email.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body))
                {
                    await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```