# UserManager.SendEmailAsync doesnt send

Tags: c#, asynchronous, smtp

I'm trying to send an email with SmtpClient.SendMailAsync and it doesn't work although the synchronous version works (SmtpClient.Send).

My synchronous code :

```
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("someEmail@gmail.com", "SomeOne"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@group.com", "You2");
            msg.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
            msg.Body = "This is a test message";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Port = 25; 
            client.Host = "mail.group.com";
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
```

My asynchronous email code (I just modified the EmailService : IIdentityMessageService class) :

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{

    const string sentFrom = "support@group.com";

    // Configure the client:
    var client = new SmtpClient("mail.group.com")
    {
        Port = 25,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        EnableSsl = true
    };

    // Create the message:
    var mail = new MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);

    // Send:
    return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

Edit : the calling code is generated by Visual Studio, here it is :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // Send an email with this link
                     string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                     var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                     await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmer votre compte", "S'il vous plaît, cliquez le lien suivant :  <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">Activation</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Why not make a fire and forget ? just change the method to `async void` and call await in `client.SendMailAsync(mail)`

Comment: Because it's already like this in the code generated by MVC. Nice name :-)

Comment: It is most probably a combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797845/asp-net-identity-2-0-how-to-implement-iidentitymessageservice-to-do-async-smtp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock

Comment: @MusicAndCode Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are returning the `Task` instead of `void`, you will need to make sure in your calling code you `await` the returned `Task`, or use `.Wait()`.

In this case, there is no need to make your `SendAsync` method `async` and `await` the `SendMailAsync` call, but if you are in doubt, then you typically should just to avoid some nasty edge cases.

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried before this version but still no success

Comment: So what is happening when you debug it, does it step through these methods ok? Is there an exception?

Comment: No exception, everything seems fine.

Comment: In the calling code snippet, you aren't calling `SendAsync` anywhere, are you calling it deeper in the stack?

Comment: It is called through :  await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmer votre compte", "S'il vous plaît, cliquez le lien suivant :  <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">Activation</a>");

Comment: I still cannot see where `SendAsync` method is called, not `SendEmailAsync`.

Comment: It is through some mecanic of MVC/Identiy. They add the interface to the manager. Dound my mistake though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just talked to my server guy. The problem was that support@group.com is blocked by the email server but not no-reply@group.com.